# Вывод в RecyclerView количества записей из другой таблицы

Tags: android, android-room

Есть две таблицы `Category` и `Bluda`. Хочу вывесит в `RecyclerView` список категорий, он при этом, чтобы также в списке отображалось количество блюд из конкретной категории.

В `DAO` такой метод

```
@Query("SELECT c.id, c.name, c.icon, c.image, count(b.id) AS cnt from category c LEFT JOIN bluda b ON c.id=b.categoryid GROUP BY c.id")
public abstract DataSource.Factory<Integer, Category> getAllCategories();
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как в адаптере получить cnt и вывести рядом с названием каждой категории?

Сделал пока что так: в класс модель добавить переменную cnt, в конструкторе также проинициализировал, а также создал геттер. Работает все, но правильно ли это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете создать новый класс, наследованный от Category, который будет иметь поле cnt

```
public class ExtCategory extended Category{
     public int cnt = 0;
     public ExtCategory(*все поля Category*, int cnt){
          super(*все поля Category*);
          this.cnt = cnt;
     }
}

@Query("SELECT c.id, c.name, c.icon, c.image, count(b.id) AS cnt from category c LEFT JOIN bluda b ON c.id=b.categoryid GROUP BY c.id")
public abstract List<ExtCategory> getAllCategories();
```

Comment: Спасибо.. Лучше наследоваться на самом деле.